How to interact with an android button back in a Python mobile app
I'm creating a mobile application for android. The application has many pages and a navigation system. However, if you go to some pages and click on the system back button, you return not one page back, but to the start page. The applications have their own appbar that works properly, but how can I fix this with the Android system back button?
I write code in Python using the Flet framework.
import flet as ft
from flet import (
Page,
Container,
Row,
Icon,
icons,
Text,
ElevatedButton,
View,
AppBar,
IconButton,
Divider,
)
class App1:
def main(page: Page):
    

    page.title = "App1"


    def route_change(route):
     page.views.clear()
     page.views.append(
            View(
                "/",
                [   
                    Text(value="Application", font_family="Calibri", size=54,),
                    Divider(color="blue", height=100),
                    ElevatedButton("Start", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/main_menu")),    
                ],
                bgcolor="blue",
                horizontal_alignment="center",
                padding=90
                
            )
        )
     
     if page.route == "/main_menu":
        page.views.append(
           View(
              "/main_menu",
              [
                    AppBar(bgcolor="green"), on_click=lambda _: page.go("/")
                    Text(value="Example1", size=32, font_family="Open Sans", color="black",),
                    Divider(height=50, color="white"),
                    Row(
                        [
                        Container(Icon(name=icons.APPLE), on_click=lambda _: page.go("/section1"),padding=20),
                        Container(Icon(name=icons.MUSIC_NOTE), on_click=lambda _: page.go("/section2"),padding=20)
                        ]
                    ),
              ],
              bgcolor="white"
           )
        )


     if page.route == "/section1":
        page.views.append(
           View(
              "/section1",
              [
                 AppBar(leading=((IconButton(icon=icons.ARROW_BACK, on_click=lambda _: page.go("/main_menu"), icon_color="black"))),
                        bgcolor="green",),
                 Text("Section1")
              ],
           )
        )

     if page.route == "/section2":
        page.views.append(
           View(
              "/section2",
              [
                 AppBar(leading=((IconButton(icon=icons.ARROW_BACK, on_click=lambda _: page.go("/main_menu"), icon_color="black"))),
                        bgcolor="green",),
                 Text("Section2")
              ],
           )
        )



     page.update()

    

    def view_pop(view):
     page.views.pop()
     top_view = page.views[-1]
     page.go(top_view.route)
    

    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.on_view_pop = view_pop
    page.go(page.route)
    

ft.app(target=main,)

`

just dont clear the views on the route_change
def route_change(e: ft.RouteChangeEvent):
    # page.views.clear()
    views_handler(page)
    page.update()

def view_pop(e: ft.ViewPopEvent):
    page.views.pop()
    top_view = page.views[-1]
    page.go(top_view.route)
    page.views.pop()

i recommend to use a handler for the views, in a separate file like:
import flet as ft
from flet import TemplateRoute

def views_handler(page):
    troute = TemplateRoute(page.route)

    if troute.match("/"):
        if load_token(page):
            page.views.append(
                Home(page, troute.route)
            )
        else:
            page.views.clear() # for clearing the views
            page.views.append(
                Home_external(page, troute.route)
            )
    elif troute.match("/login"):
        page.views.append(
            Login(page, troute.route)
        )
    elif troute.match("/forgotpassword"):
        page.views.append(
            ForgotPassword(page, troute.route)
        )

